# Bootstrap enable button on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some issues getting this done correctly.
I want my "sendit" button to enable (remove disable) as soon as there is any characters in the box.
I've tried multiple things now but I can not get it to work.


**Part of HTML:**

```
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <input id="sendit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block disabled" type="submit" value="Generate Codes"></input>
```

**JS File**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var pass_error = 1;

    // Check name field

        if (inputPassword === '') {
            pass_error = 1;
        } else {
            pass_error = 0;
        }
        enableButton();
    });


    // verzendknop pas activeren nadat alles is ingevuld en gecontroleerd
    function enableButton() {
        if (pass_error!== 0) {
            $('#btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Don't use the `disabled` class in your `<input>`'s HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only checks the field once upon DOM Ready.

You need to tie your check to a keyUp event on that field:

```
$('my-field').keyUp(function() {
 if($(this).val() === '') {
  pass_error = 1;
} else {
  pass_error = 0;
  enableButton();
});
```